# How to test if a windows group exists from inno setup?

Tags: inno-setup

How can you test to see if a windows group is already setup? Can you somehow use the response from:

```
Exec('net.exe', 'localgroup', '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, Result);
```

which will list the groups to the command prompt?  (I know that Result is an error code where 0 is success, just to be clear.)

Is there a way? Is there more than one way?

Comment: What about using {groupname}? I think that will usually be the group name for the current user. Is it?

Comment: No, {groupname} is "the name of the folder the user selected on Setup's Select Start Menu Folder wizard page. This differs from {group} in that it is only the name; it does not include a path." Did you try my solution below?

Comment: I missed a few words when I read that in the documentation. I must have been crossing my eyes, thanks. No I did not try it, but I can see how it would indeed work.. I may still need to try it in the future but for now I am on to something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested this, or had time to work out the exact process or syntax, but you could possibly use command redirection (see https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx), using `net localgroup` as you suggested, to find the group name and output it to a text file. You could then read it into Inno Setup using `LoadStringFromFile`, then all you would need to do is compare the two strings.

So, having looked at this in more detail, to see if the Administrators group exists you could use:

```
[Run]
Filename: "{cmd}"; Parameters: "/c ""net localgroup | find /i ""Administrators"" > ""{tmp}\groupresult.txt"""""; StatusMsg: "Querying user groups..."; Flags: runhidden

[Code]
var
  strGroupResult: String;
begin
  LoadStringFromFile(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\groupresult.txt'), strGroupResult);
  if strGroupResult = '*Administrators' then
    begin
    //Code to execute if group exists
    ...
    end;
  DeleteFile(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\groupresult.txt'));
end;
```

Note that `net localgroup` returns an asterisk (*) in front of the group name, so the string comparison needs to also include the asterisk.

If you need to do this before the `[Run]` section, you can write a similar `Exec` line in the `[Code]` section to run the same process.